# Why wont Java run this code?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a ProcessBuilder named pb. The class has the following Constructor:

```
public Server(JSONObject root) {
    this.jv = new JarVersion( (JSONObject) root.get("jarV") );

    this.ram = Integer.parseInt(root.get("ram").toString());
    this.name = root.get("name").toString();
    this.unit = size.valueOf( root.get("size") .toString().toUpperCase() );

    String wpath = Core.serverpath + fls + this.name;

    String cmd = "java -Xmx"+this.ram;
    cmd += this.unit.getShort(this.unit) + " ";
    cmd += "-jar ";

    cmd += wpath + fls + jv.getFullVersion() + ".jar";

    pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.directory(new File( wpath ));
}
```

My Current pb has this command: "java -Xmx1024M -jar C:\Users[USERNAME]\Desktop\SLV2_DATA\server\test\spigot-1.11.1.jar".

The path is available and this command is working from CMD.exe i don't know why it won't in the class ?

Why does this command cannot be executed?
This is the error I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -Xmx1024M -jar C:\Users\RicheeNektar\Desktop\SLV2_DATA\server\test\spigot-1.11.1.jar" (in directory "C:\Users\RicheeNektar\Desktop\SLV2_DATA\server\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.RicheeNektar.Resources.Server.start(Server.java:90)
at org.RicheeNektar.frames.Console.<init>(Console.java:176)
at org.RicheeNektar.ServerPanel.Core$5.actionPerformed(Core.java:345)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 41 more
```

Comment: A) arguments should come as array of strings, instead of one long string with spaces B) I read the message as "java" cant be found. Could it be that java isn't in your PATH? Maybe you should use an absolute path pointing to the java.exe binary as well.

Comment: It looks like the error message thinks you are looking for a binary named for your full string, not "java".

Comment: It works :D Thanks